# Error when atempting to install Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation

Attemping a new install of Ubuntu 12.04 on what was a Windows XP laptop (HP Pavilon ze4500 with 40GB HDD). Downloaded the ISO image and burned to a DVD. Seems to copy all files OK, askes for location and keyboard and after a while reports

> Installation failed, The installer encountered an unrecoverable error. A desktop session will now be run so that you may investigate the problem or try installing again.

I am completly new to Linux and have little technical knowledge so simple advice as how to proceed will be welcome. Thank you.

Follows one example of an attempt to install.

#### Install Ubuntu

- tick for 4.4 GB available, is connected to the internet, other 2 option not ticked this  time

  - Option 1 Install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS alongside Install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - not selected
  - Erase Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and reinstall - not taken
  - Something else - Selected

  /dev/sda
  /dev/sda1 ext4     39000 MB with 2909 MB used
  /dev/sda swap     1004 MB with 0 MB used

New Partition Table

> You have selected an entire devices to partition... all current partitions will be 
>   removed - can be undone if wished

Now shows

```
/dev/sda free space               40007MB
```

Selected ADD.

Create a new partition

- Primary or Logical - took default of Primary
- New partition size changed from 40007 MB to 39000 MB
- Location for new partition - took default of Beginning (rather than end)
- Use as Ext4journaling file system (don't understand the choices anyway)
- Set Mount point with / (found this on the Internet otherwise would have never known what to put into here)

Now shows

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sda ext 4 / tick under Format?, size 38998 MB type unknown 
free space 1008 MB - changed the type to swap
```

#### Install now

After some time the install fails

> The installer encountered a unrecoverable error. A desktop session will not be run so that you may investigate the problem or try installing again

Finally

> System program problem detected

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling it again choosing:

> Erase Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and reinstall